# How could I clear a perl script error in implementing the net-snmp agent?

Tags: perl, net-snmp

I now am implementing the net-snmp agent on the Ubuntu 16.04, by referring this site
(https://kadionik.vvv.enseirb-matmeca.fr/embedded/snmp/english/net-snmp_english.html)

But I stopped at the '4.2 NET-SNMP Agent Extension'

When I executes ‘perl Makefile.PL’, the following error message is displayed.(perl version : 5.22.1)

> Can't locate MakefileSubs.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
> MakefileSubs module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl
> /usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.22.1
> /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.22
> /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.22
> /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl
> /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl-base .) at Makefile.PL line 7. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 7.

The following is the Perl Script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
require 5;
use Config;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
use MakefileSubs;

my $lib_version;

WriteMakefile(DefaultStoreInitMakeParams());

sub DefaultStoreInitMakeParams {
    my $opts;
    my %Params = (
      'NAME'        => 'NetSNMP::default_store',
      'VERSION_FROM'    => 'default_store.pm', # finds $VERSION
      'XSPROTOARG'          => '-prototypes',
      );

AddCommonParams(\%Params);
              
my ($snmp_lib, $snmp_llib, $sep);

$opts = NetSNMPGetOpts();

if ($Config{'osname'} eq 'MSWin32' && !defined($ENV{'OSTYPE'})) {
  $sep = '\\';
  my $snmp_lib_file = 'netsnmp.lib';
  my $snmp_link_lib = 'netsnmp';
  my $lib_dir;

  if (lc($opts->{'debug'}) eq "true") {
    $lib_dir = 'lib\\debug';
  }
  else {
    $lib_dir = 'lib\\release';
  }
  
  if (lc($opts->{'insource'}) eq "true") {
$Params{'LIBS'} = "-L" . $MakefileSubs::basedir . "\\win32\\$lib_dir\\ -l$snmp_link_lib";
  }
  else {
my @LibDirs = split($Config{path_sep}, $ENV{LIB});
    my $LibDir;
if ($opts->{'prefix'}) {
  push (@LibDirs,"$ENV{'NET-SNMP-PATH'}${sep}lib");
}
my $noLibDir = 1;
while ($noLibDir) {
  $LibDir = find_files(["$snmp_lib_file"],\@LibDirs);
  if ($LibDir ne '') {
    $noLibDir = 0;
        # Put quotes around LibDir to allow spaces in paths
        $LibDir = '"' . $LibDir . '"';
  }
  else
  {
    @LibDirs = ();
    $LibDirs[0] = prompt("The Net-SNMP library ($snmp_lib_file) could not be found.\nPlease enter the directory where it is located:");
    $LibDirs[0] =~ s/\\$//;
  }
}
$Params{LIBS} = "-L$LibDir -l$snmp_link_lib";
  }
}
else {
$Params{'LIBS'}    = `$opts->{'nsconfig'} --libs` or
    die "net-snmp-config failed\n";
chomp($Params{'LIBS'});
    $lib_version = `$opts->{'nsconfig'} --version` or
    die "net-snmp-config failed\n";
if (lc($opts->{'insource'}) eq "true") {
    $Params{'LIBS'} =
            "-L" . abs_path("../../snmplib/.libs") .
            " -L" . abs_path("../../snmplib") .
            " " . $Params{'LIBS'};
}
}

return(%Params);
}
```

I have checked many recommendation to clear this problem, and installed some packages, ‘libsnmp-perl’, ‘libnet-snmp-perl’.

But I yet don’t cleared this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The net-snmp distribution (not the Perl module) has a directory named *perl/* with a *Makefile.PL*. I assume that you are in this directory. Under *perl/*, there is a file named *MakefileSubs.pm*. For a Perl program to load that, it needs to know to look in the current directory to find *MakefileSubs.pm*. When you look at the error message, you see the list of directories that perl search; it doesn't look like the `.` is there is there.

As an aside, the current working directory, `.`, was [removed from the default module search path in Perl v5.26](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/01/v5-26-removes-dot-from-inc/), but you are using an earlier version and it looks like someone decided on a different set of directories for the default search path.

One way to do that is to specify the additional directory with the `-I` switch and use `.` for the current directory:

```
$ perl -I. Makefile.PL
```

Or perhaps more safely:

```
$ perl -I`pwd` Makefile.PL
```

You can also add this directory to the PERL5LIB environment variable so anything in your session will search that directory too:

```
% export PERL5LIB = `pwd`:$PERL5LIB
```

[How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-(@INC)-at-runtime?)